# Why does xlib interfere XNVCtrl calls?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, nvidia, xlib

I am practicing with threads in C. My program have to constantly (periodically) poll free GPU memory (and other info), while being able to handle X events. The problem is when I am calling `XNVCTRLQueryTargetAttribute`, the program freezes and eat 100% of 1 core. Here is the code, simplified but buggy as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include "NVCtrl/NVCtrl.h"
#include "NVCtrl/NVCtrlLib.h"

Display *display;
pthread_t t1, t2;

void *run(void *t)
{
    XEvent e;
    int total;
    int gpu = 0;

    if(t == &t1) {
        while(1) {
            XNVCTRLQueryTargetAttribute(display, NV_CTRL_TARGET_TYPE_GPU, gpu, 0,
                NV_CTRL_TOTAL_DEDICATED_GPU_MEMORY, &total);
            fprintf(stderr, "total memory: %d\n", total);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        XNextEvent(display, &e);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(!(display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
        return 1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, run, (void *) &t1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, run, (void *) &t2);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And command I use. **In order to compile the program you need Nvidia graphics card and proprietary driver**.

```
cc -lpthread -lX11 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o foo foo.c /usr/lib/libXNVCtrl.so
```

When I comment out `XNextEvent(display, &e);` line or the one with `XNVCTRLQueryTargetAttribute` call, each second "total memory: 0" is printed to the terminal. Otherwise, there is nothing.

I just tested without threads and see no high cpu usage. Moved the following code to `main`.

```
XNVCTRLQueryTargetAttribute(display, NV_CTRL_TARGET_TYPE_GPU, gpu, 0,
    NV_CTRL_TOTAL_DEDICATED_GPU_MEMORY, &total);
fprintf(stderr, "total memory: %d\n", total);
XNextEvent(display, &e);
sleep(1);
```

Message "total memory: 1996" is printed, then `XNextEvent` blocks for eternity (because of no listeners). I suppose the problem is that I do not understand threads well, perhaps in combination with dynamic linking. I doubt it matter, but anyway, nvidia driver: 435.21-11.

Comment: Most likely. I had some success with `XInitThreads` but it only fixed cpu usage. XLockDisplay had no effect at all. There are other options (like using xcb instead of xlib) but I will probably open another `Display *` connection for nvidia calls. But I still do not understand the reason. It seems like thread related issue, but without XNVCtrl calls all is fine (I have 2 threads, both utilize one `Display *` connection). I can imagine that both processes try to access one socket which is busy after `XNextEvent` call. Anyway, I am too noob in C/system programming to make such assumptions.

Comment: I will mark this as duplicate soon, so if anyone has something to say about the issue, it is the right time.